# In Python, my functions don't return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

When I ran the program, it didn't return me the values that were inputed which was `num1` and `num2`.

Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

print('Lists of operations: ')
print('1. add')
print('2. subtract')
print('3. multiply')
print('4. divide')

operations = int(input('Select an operation (1/2/3/4): '))

num1 = float(input('Enter a number: '))
num2 = float(input('Enter a number: '))
# Functions aren't returning values
if '1' == operations:
    print(num1,'+',num2,'equals'+ add(num1, num2))
# Functions aren't returning values
elif '2' == operations:
    print(num1,'-',num2,'equals', subtract(num1, num2))
# Functions aren't returning values
elif '3' == operations:
    print(num1,'*',num2,'equals', multiply(num1, num2))
# Functions aren't returning values
elif '4' == operations:
    print(num1,'/',num2,'equals', divide(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Every function returns some value, even if it's `None`. Please [edit] your question to give the exact output or error of your program.

Comment: Actually, it's clear from what you posted, sorry. It's just a typo. You used `int()` to make `operations` an `int`, but then you compared it to strings instead of integers.

Comment: Use proper Python comments please. It's fine to annotate the error inline, but please be consistent

Comment: If your first thought is, that there is a bug in Python, then you might need to change the way you think about correcting errors

Comment: In the future it will help you to make a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing integers to strings:

```
if '1' == operations:
```

Use `1` instead of `'1'` and the same for other numbers:

```
if 1 == operations:
```